# jQuery Select Box is cropped scrollpane

Tags: javascript, html, css, jscrollpane, drop-down-menu

I use two jQuery plugins for my site: `jquery.selectbox.js` and `jquery.jscrollpane.js`.

**`selectbox.js`** turns my selects into the set of `div`s and `jscrollpane.js` add custom scroll bars to the content. And I ran into a problem when I put select-box into the `jscrollpane`. *`jscrollpane`* crops everything that outs of its borders - even selectbox dropdown. Can you help me with this?

[image: Pic 2]
[image: Pic 1]

Comment: Before we go further into jQuery, check this: [Grammar Structures for **cut**](http://esl.about.com/od/grammarstructures/a/v_cut.htm)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.jscrollpane`, has `overflow:scroll` in css class definition.

That's what breaking your presentation, 'cause wrapper element with defined overflow will not really allow child elements to exceed it's own dimensions.

You may try to set the `position` property of your select box to `absolute` when dropdown appears, but you'll have to mess with calculation of element's position relative to document, in order to have it at right place.

Comment: It's good solution. I'll try. But may there is something simpler